# Restrict server from accepting connections on a certain port from a different hostname

Tags: linux, centos, port

I have some services running on my server. The server is reachable under other domains, too. I made some subdomains to separate the services from each other but they can be reached from the main domain as well as on the other domains.

I'd like to know how I can restrict my server from accepting connections on certain ports. So that I can for example make my mail server only under `mail.example.com` reachable.
The server is running CentOS 7

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service running on any port doesn't know which hostname the user is using to connect unless the protocol using the port has a method of changing that information, like HTTP does with `Host:` header. Otherwise, after the hostname has been resolved to an IP address with DNS, the IP address is used for the connection. Therefore, firewalls can't distinguish the hostnames from each other.

If you don't want for example your SMTP server  to be available from other addresses, you must have dedicated IP address for it. Usually there's no reason for that, as it causes no harm at all. It's another MTA  that connects to the server based on `MX` record (or an email client), not any user directly. Also, SMTP advertises it's hostname in SMTP banner.

For web servers, as the HTTP protocol includes information on the hostname, it's possible to serve different content on different hostname, i.e. to use [Name-based Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html). With HTTPS the same is possible using [Server Name Indication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4366#section-3.1) (SNI).